# Create new columns in Spark dataframe based on a hundred column pairs

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create around 9-10 columns based on values in 100 of columns(sch0,shm2...shm100) , however values of these columns would be the value in columns(idm0,idm1....idm100) which is part of same dataframe.

There are additional columns as well apart from these 2 pairs of 100.
Problem is, not all the scheme (schm0,schm1..schm100) would have values in it and we have to traverse through each to find out the values and create the columns accordingly, 85+ columns would be empty most of the time so we need to ignore them.

Input dataframe example:

```
+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|col1|col2|col3|sch0|idsm0|schm1|idsm1|schm2|idsm2|schm3|idsm3|
+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   a|   b|   c|   0|    1|    2|    3|    4|    5| null| null|
+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

`schm` and `idsm` can go upto 100, so its basically the key-value pairs of 100 columns.

Expected output:

```
----+----+----+----------+-------+-------+
|col1|col2|col3|found_zero|found_2|found_4|
+----+----+----+----------+-------+-------+
|   a|   b|   c|         1|      3|      5|
+----+----+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

Note: There is no fixed value in any column, any columns can have any value and the columns that we create has to be based on value found in any of the scheme columns (`schm0`...`schm100`) and the values in the created columns would be corresponding values of scheme i.e idsymbol (`idsm0`...`idsm100`)

I am finding it difficult to formulate a plan to do it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edited-
Adding another input example--

```
col1|col2|schm_0|idsm_0|schm_1|idsm_1|schm_2|idsm_2|schm_3|idsm_3|schm_4|idsm_4|schm_5|idsm_5|
+----+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   2|   6|    b1|   id1|     i|   id2|    xs|   id3|    ch|   id4|  null|  null|  null|  null|
|   3|   5|    b2|   id5|    x2|   id6|    ch|   id7|    be|   id8|  null|  null|    db|  id15|
|   4|   7|    b1|   id9|    ch|  id10|    xs|  id11|    us|  id12|  null|  null|  null|  null|
+----+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

for one particular record, col(schm_0,schm_1....schm_100) can have around 9 to 10 unique values as not all the columns would be populated with values.

we need to create 9 different columns based on the 9 unique values, so in short for one row  , we need to iterate over each of 100 schmeme columns and collect all the values which is found there, based on found values, separate columns need to be created...and the values in those created columns would be the value in idsm(idsm_0,idsm_1....idsm_100)

i.e if schm_0 has value 'cb' we need to create new column for eg 'col_cb' and value in this column 'col_cb' would be value in 'idsm_0' column.
similarly we need to do for all 100 columns(we need to leave out the empty ones).

Expected output-

```
+----+----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|col1|col2|col_b1|col_b2|col_i|col_x2|col_ch|col_xs|col_be|col_us|col_db|
+----+----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   2|   6|   id1|  null|  id2|  null|   id4|   id3|  null|  null|  null|
|   3|   5|  null|   id5| null|   id6|   1d7|  null|   id8|  null|  id15|
|   4|   7|   id9|  null| null|  null|  1d10|  id11|  null|  id12|  null|
+----+----+------+------+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Hope this clears the problem statements.
Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Editing again for small issue-

as we see in above example , the columns that we create is based on the values found in schemesymbol columns,and there is already a defined set of columns that will get created which is 10 in numbers..columns for eg would be (col_a,col_b,col_c,cold_d,col_e,col_f,col_g_col_h,col_i,col_j)

not all the 10 keywords i.e(a,b,c....j) would be present all time in dataset under (shcheme0.....scheme99).

Requirement is we need to pass all 10 columns, if some of the keys(a,b,c...j) is not present ,the column created would be having null values.

Comment: Can you give or expand your example with multiple records as input and the output that you expect for it? Just seeing the output of single record and your description makes it confusing.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya , sorry to have not made it quite clear, i have added few more example..hope that helps.

Comment: See the answer that I posted..

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya Thanks for the quick response, this seems to work fine with smaller set of scheme and idsybmol columns but as I mentioned I have hundred of each columns in a real case, so putting all those 100 coulmns in stack would be wise?  or can we try something like Map, where we can ietarte over 100 columns and store scheme and idsm as key values pairs and later do the conditional column creation on the values stored in map.

Comment: @Arjun_Jha Based on my knowledge you can use map to make it more dynamic along with stack function but don't know without stack. And iterating through all the columns would make it more involved but will check and see if I find more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: See if the updated answer works for you.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya yes, let me try this one..thanks !

Comment: Hi @NikunjKakadiya, this solution is working to some extent, but I see idsmbol values being duplicated across few schemesybmol columns, i.e same value from idsybmol is being feed into two or more different columns, looking at your code ..can hardly say it can cause this, any further insight into this would be helpful

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya, never mind..I missed out one part of the code..let me try again..thanks

Comment: hi @NikunjKakadiya, solution is working fine, but I see one challnage in my use case, have edited the post again..pls have a look...Thanks much

Comment: In that case you would have to hardcode all the column names and apply the logic. There is no way apart from that.

Comment: yes, Thats what I did ..thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required output that you are expecting but would be a multi step process.

First you would have to create two separate dataframes out of the original dataframe i.e one which contains schm columns and other which contains idsm columns. You will have to unpivot schm columns and idsm columns.

Then you would join both the dataframes based on unique combination of columns  and filter the dataframe based on null values. You would then do group by based on unique columns and pivot on the schm columns and get the first value of the idsm columns.

```
//Sample Data
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val initialdf = Seq((2,6,"b1","id1","i","id2","xs","id3","ch","id4",null,null,null,null),(3,5,"b2","id5","x2","id6","ch","id7","be","id8",null,null,"db","id15"),(4,7,"b1","id9","ch","id10","xs","id11","us","id12","es","id00",null,null)).toDF("col1","col2","schm_0","idsm_0","schm_1","idsm_1","schm_2","idsm_2","schm_3","idsm_3","schm_4","idsm_4","schm_5","idsm_5")
//creating two separate dataframes
val schmdf = initialdf.selectExpr("col1","col2", "stack(6, 'schm_0',schm_0, 'schm_1',schm_1,'schm_2',schm_2,'schm_3' ,schm_3, 'schm_4',schm_4,'schm_5',schm_5) as (schm,schm_value)").withColumn("id",split($"schm", "_")(1))
val idsmdf = initialdf.selectExpr("col1","col2", "stack(6, 'idsm_0',idsm_0, 'idsm_1',idsm_1,'idsm_2',idsm_2,'idsm_3' ,idsm_3, 'idsm_4',idsm_4,'idsm_5',idsm_5) as (idsm,idsm_value)").withColumn("id",split($"idsm", "_")(1))
//joining two dataframes and applying filter operation and giving alias for the column names to be used in next operation
val df = schmdf.join(idsmdf,Seq("col1","col2","id"),"inner").filter($"idsm_value" =!= "null").select("col1","col2","schm","schm_value","idsm","idsm_value").withColumn("schm_value", concat(lit("col_"),$"schm_value"))

df.groupBy("col1","col2").pivot("schm_value").agg(first("idsm_value")).show
```

you can see the output as below :

```
+----+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+
|col1|col2|col_b1|col_b2|col_be|col_ch|col_db|col_es|col_i|col_us|col_x2|col_xs|
+----+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+
|   2|   6|   id1|  null|  null|   id4|  null|  null|  id2|  null|  null|   id3|
|   3|   5|  null|   id5|   id8|   id7|  id15|  null| null|  null|   id6|  null|
|   4|   7|   id9|  null|  null|  id10|  null|  id00| null|  id12|  null|  id11|
+----+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----+------+------+------+
```

**Updated Answer using Map:**

If you have n number of columns and you know them in advance you can use the below approach which is more generic as compared to above approach.

```
//sample Data
val initialdf = Seq((2,6,"b1","id1","i","id2","xs","id3","ch","id4",null,null,null,null),(3,5,"b2","id5","x2","id6","ch","id7","be","id8",null,null,"db","id15"),(4,7,"b1","id9","ch","id10","xs","id11","us","id12","es","id00",null,null)).toDF("col1","col2","schm_0","idsm_0","schm_1","idsm_1","schm_2","idsm_2","schm_3","idsm_3","schm_4","idsm_4","schm_5","idsm_5")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val schmcols = Seq("schm_0", "schm_1", "schm_2","schm_3","schm_4","schm_5")
val schmdf = initialdf.select($"col1",$"col2", explode(array(
                schmcols.map(column =>
                    struct(    
                        lit(column).alias("schm"),
                        col(column).alias("schm_value")
                    )): _*
        )).alias("schmColumn"))
.withColumn("id",split($"schmColumn.schm", "_")(1))
.withColumn("schm",$"schmColumn.schm")
.withColumn("schm_value",$"schmColumn.schm_value").drop("schmColumn")

val idcols = Seq("idsm_0", "idsm_1", "idsm_2","idsm_3","idsm_4","idsm_5")
val idsmdf = initialdf.select($"col1",$"col2", explode(array(
              idcols.map(
                column =>
                    struct(    
                        lit(column).alias("idsm"),
                        col(column).alias("idsm_value")
                    )): _*
               )).alias("idsmColumn"))
.withColumn("id",split($"idsmColumn.idsm", "_")(1))
.withColumn("idsm",$"idsmColumn.idsm")
.withColumn("idsm_value",$"idsmColumn.idsm_value").drop("idsmColumn")

val df = schmdf.join(idsmdf,Seq("col1","col2","id"),"inner")
.filter($"idsm_value" =!= "null")
.select("col1","col2","schm","schm_value","idsm","idsm_value")
.withColumn("schm_value", concat(lit("col_"),$"schm_value"))

df.groupBy("col1","col2").pivot("schm_value")
.agg(first("idsm_value")).show
```